# Iptables rules for NATing to DNS server in VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, iptables, wireless-access-point

I am currently setting up a Raspberry Pi to facilitate connecting to my company's VPN from home. The Pi has the following interfaces:

- `eth0` -- Connected to my ISP router.
- `tun0` -- The OpenVPN tunnel interface connecting to the company VPN.
- `wlan0` -- Configured as a wireless access point.

I have set up the following iptables rules to bridge all traffic between `wlan0` and `tun0` (NATing has been enabled):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks as follows:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search a.my-company.com b.my-company.com c.my-company.com
nameserver 10.0.0.1           # VPN DNS server
nameserver 10.4.0.1           # VPN DNS server
nameserver 194.168.4.100      # ISP DNS server
nameserver 194.168.8.100      # ISP DNS server
```

From the Pi, I can resolve and reach both VPN hosts and external hosts. However, devices connected to the wireless access point cannot resolve either (but reaching VPN hosts by IP works). I am not sure if my diagnosis pins down the problem correctly, but I have noticed that a TCPdump on `tun0` contains:

```
IP 10.4.119.198.35387 > [VPN DNS SERVER 1].domain: 12662+ A? some.website.com. (38)
IP [VPN DNS SERVER 1].domain > 10.4.119.198.35387: 12662 1/13/13 A [Resolved IP] (486)
IP 10.4.119.198 > [VPN DNS SERVER 1]: ICMP 10.4.119.198 udp port 35387 unreachable, length 522
```

This seems to indicate that something is filtering DNS responses.

I am not familiar with configuring such set-ups, so any help with this would be appreciated! I will of course be happy to provide more information if needed.